# Can SELECT expressions sometimes be evaluated for rows not matching WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know if it's possible for expressions that are part of the `SELECT` statement list to be evaluated for rows not matching the `WHERE` clause?

From the execution order [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189499.aspx), it seems that the `SELECT` gets evaluated long after the `WHERE`, however I ran into a very weird problem with a real-life query **similar to the query below**.

To put you in context, in the example, the `SomeOtherTable` has a `a_varchar` column which always contains numerical values for the `code` 105, but may contain non-numerical values for other codes.

The query statement works:

```
    SELECT an_id, an_integer FROM SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT an_id, CAST(a_varchar AS int)
    FROM SomeOtherTable
    WHERE code = 105
```

The following query complains about being unable to cast `a_varchar` to `int`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (
    SELECT an_id, an_integer FROM SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT an_id, CAST(a_varchar AS int)
    FROM SomeOtherTable
    WHERE code = 105
) i
INNER JOIN AnotherOne a
    ON a.an_id = i.an_id
```

And finally, the following query works:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (
    SELECT an_id, an_integer FROM SomeTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        an_id, 
        CASE code WHEN 105 THEN CAST(a_varchar AS int) ELSE NULL END
    FROM SomeOtherTable
    WHERE code = 105
) i
INNER JOIN AnotherOne a
    ON a.an_id = i.an_id
```

Therefore, the only explanation I could find was that with the `JOIN`, the query gets optimized differently in a way that `CAST(a_varchar AS int)` gets executed even if `code <> 105`.

The queries are run against SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: Yes, expressions can (and will) be evaluated regardless of WHERE clause. Like you discovered yourself, use CASE expressions.

Comment: Actually, the oddest thing about this is that column reduction should have eliminated *all* of the column expressions entirely.  Other than that this is (unfortunately) not unexpected behavior.  Proper bracketing of expressions with `CASE` is the SOP way around it (almost always works).

Comment: I would be curious if you have the same problem without the union.  I have a sneaking suspicion that the UNION ALL is evaluating the data types in the select and seeing one as varchar and giving up before it realizes you're doing a cast. WHEN Contained within a sub query.    So can you try without the first select and union.  IN addition instead of creating a materialized subquery, this may work with a CTE...

Comment: @xQbert No this is no bug (except possibly the column reduction thing I mentioned above).  This is  just how it works.

Comment: @Rbarryyoung Excellent Learned something new; although, then why does his first statement work then?

Comment: @xQbert Its differences in query optimization.  The actual evaluation order is inconsistent and ultimately determined by the optimizer, which is documented.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Could you point me to docs explaining in which situations the optimizer choses to evaluate expressions that logically wouldn't need to be evaluated. That design decision doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @plalx That's because you are thinking of these bounded scalar column expressions as important to performance optimization, they are not.  Optimizations in SQL have very little to do with expression overhead and everything to do with disk IOs, in-memory rowset sizes and (avoiding) sorting.  These are the priorities that primarily inform the optimizer's behavior.  OTOH, it *is* supposed to do column reductions of rowsets (completely eliminating unused columns) but this is because it can allow for more efficient table/index usage.  Still, it is odd that it didn't just eliminate them...

Comment: I cannot get the symptoms you describe, perhaps the data I have assumed is "wrong" http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79d6d/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely.

The documentation that you reference has a section called **Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement**.  This is not the physical processing order.  It explains how the query itself is interpreted.  For instance, an alias defined in the `select` clause cannot be references in the `where` clause, because the `where` clause is *logically* processed first.

In fact, SQL Server has the ability to optimize queries by doing various data transformation operations when it reads the data.  This is a nice performance benefit, because the data is in memory, locally, and the operations can simply be done in place.  However, the following can fail with a run-time error:

```
select cast(a_varchar as int)
from table t
where a_varchar not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

The filter is applied *after* the attempt at conversion, in the real process flow.  I happen to consider this a bug; presumably, the folks at Microsoft do not think so, because they have not bothered to fix this.

Two workarounds are available.  The first is `try_convert()`, which does conversions and returns `NULL` for a failure instead of a run-time error.  The second is the `case` statement:

```
select (case when a_varchar not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(a_varchar as int) end)
from table t
where a_varchar not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

Comment: I think that `try_convert(..)` is only available in SQL Server 2012 and later.

Comment: Yes it's definitely an odd behavior. I really do not see how interpreting expressions that wouldn't need to be would lead to better performance. Do you have any official documentation about physical processing order?

Comment: @plalx . . . This starts by understanding execution plans (one place to start:  http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/understanding-query-plans).  As for performance, moving data around has a much bigger effect on performance than doing most calculations on data already in memory.  I don't know if Microsoft explains this particular optimization, but it seems quite reasonable to me -- except for the impact it has on the semantics of the query.

Comment: HI @Gordon Linoff so, can we rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (column alias, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?